# Classification of jumbled images

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision

I want to be able to create a model that would be able to classify an image that has been split into 9 parts and jumbled around.

I did see a paper on it but it is quite old (7-8 years old). Could anyone point me towards any resources? Is building a CNN the best approach?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to classify it based on the content as if it had not been jumbled, like a typical image recognition problem?

Answer (score 1):

[This 2019 paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SkfMWhAqYQ) states that all the current image classification models are actually doing the same thing, i.e. classifying jumbled image patches. The reason is that they are weak at peaking up long-range dependencies (relations between pixels far away). As a result, breaking these dependencies by shuffling the image patches does not affect them substantially. Here is [a post](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/03/neural-networks-strategy-classify-images.html) that explains the findings and the **BagNet** method that suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- CNNs are indeed state-of-the-art in computer vision for image recognition, categorization, and classification. Simply taking the jumbled images and learning a mapping from them to the label via a CNN is likely to be the most straightforward and likely to work approach.
- One thing missing from the above idea for problems where the label one is trying to learn relies on some global structurally coherent aspects, which are destroyed during the scrambling. In this case, one can either try to learn to reconstruct the images (see below) or take every image and try several random rearrangements as input (per permuted image), and take, say, the prediction the network is most confident in.
- Separately, if you want to *reconstruct* the jumbled images (i.e., solve the scrambled puzzle), there are some recent papers looking at how to do exactly that. E.g.,

  - [DeepPermNet: Visual Permutation Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02729) (2017)
  - [Learning Latent Permutations with Gumbel-Sinkhorn Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08665) (2018)